# Can you create new orders using the /V1/orders/create rest API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am trying to create a new order using the /V1/orders/create rest API but when I search on google or dev docs it shows me a different set of API to do the order process (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-intro.html). So is there a way to create an order using /V1/orders/create? if none then what is the purpose of /V1/orders/create.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the **[Adobe commerce developer docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/docs/)** for the API reference

Just added below the Orders REST API endpoint for your reference.

> orders/create

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/

[image]

[image]